# Proving an IVT has a local unique solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Given a continuous function $f\colon (a,b)\rightarrow{\mathbb{R}}$ and $x_0\in (a,b)$. Consider de initial value problem
$$
\begin{cases} 
x'=f(x)\\ 
x(t_0)=x_0,
\end{cases}$$
with $f(x_0)\neq 0$. How do I prove that this IVT has a unique local solution?  I would prove that $f$ is locally Lipschitz, but I am not given the function, so I cannot see that.

Comment: $f$ need not be Lipschitz near $x_0$, it could be $f(t)=1+\sqrt{|t-x_0|}$

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics)#First_order) might be helpful.